# Какой предлог использовать: “в” или “на”?

Tags: грамотная-речь, предлоги

Допустим, что есть концертно-спортивный комплекс "Колпино арена", как нужно приглашать гостей: *на "Колпино арену"* или *в "Колпино арену"?* Я считаю, что "в" в любом случае, ведь это название бренда, а не техническое название места, мои оппоненты считают, что "на", так как есть слово "арена", но ведь если ресторан называется "Небо", мы же не скажем *пойдем на "Небо".* Рассудите, пожалуйста, желательно с разъяснением. Или, может, даже есть какое правило прописанное, чтобы указать коллегам (или себе, если не права я).

Answer (score 1):

*Колпино-арена* - неформальное название (официальное: **Ледовая Арена Колпино**), поэтому при желании употребить название сооружения на английский манер ничто не помешает написать его правильно, т. е. в одно слово и через дефис (других грамматически обоснованных способов связать эти два слова нет - порознь они останутся "в наборе"). Относиться к такому слову можно только как к разновидности "арены", которое, в свою очередь, в аспекте *местонахождения* (где) сочетается только с предлогом "**на**", но в оценочном аспекте можно себе представить и такое: "*Я нахожу особую прелесть **в** Колпино-арене*".